# Uploaded by FTP - html and css no longer linked

Tags: html, css

Completely new at web design so please bear with! I've uploaded my test site to my hosting via FTP but it seems the HTML has lost contact with the CSS - it can be seen at typespire.com

Why has this happened and how do I fix it?

Thanks for any help you can offer

Ben

Comment: did you uploaded CSS file too?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question... [Typespire](http://www.typespire.com/site/Index.html) has a css style: Typespire.css. Also, there's another style page in your server, TypespireIndex.css, that is not linked to the index. If you want to link it, you have to modify the index.html page (change the "<link rel= ..." line)

Comment: you misspelled it. Typespire.css instead of typespire.css

Answer (score 2):

### You misspelled it. You wrote typespire.css instead of Typespire.css

To fix your problem, you need to replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typespire.css">
```

by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Typespire.css">
```

Or **(better solution)** : rename your `Typespire.css` file to `typespire.css` and put this tag in your pages :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typespire.css">
```

## So you could ask : Why is it working on my computer ?

### Locally :

Some Operating Systems are case sensitive and some other are not. So, depending on the system on which you develop your website, you have to pay attention for Uppercase or Lowercase in your path.

### Through FTP :

When you are uploading files through FTP, depending on the configuration, the server would be case sensitive or not, so you have to pay attention on your path or not.

So, the best solution in your case is to write only lowercases filenames likes `typespire` and use the tag bellow :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typespire.css">
```

**You should write your filenames in lowercase letters. It will help you avoid problems**

Comment: The code linking my HTML to my CSS is <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TypespireIndex.css">

Now that this is online, should this be different?!

Comment: Ok, i click on your link and the problem is you forgot a T. You wrote `typespire.css` instead of `Typespire.css`

Comment: @BenGilchrist did you fix your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it will be hard to determine the cause.

What FTP program are you using?

Have you uploaded the CSS files to your web host?

If so, is the path that you set for the CSS files still valid on your web host?

Comment: Im using Cyberduck - CSS is uploaded - the link path is 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TypespireIndex.css"> 

as I was taught in my lesson - should this be different now it has been uploaded?

Comment: Did you upload the CSS file to the same directory that your HTML file is in?

Comment: no, but it must be located in the SAME folder as .html from with you are reffering

Comment: Since you added TypespireIndex.css without any / before it, it is basically saying to look in the same folder as this HTML file for the CSS file.  Where is your CSS file located?

Answer (score 0):

In your pages - other than index.html - you use a wrong name for the css file: **typespire.css**. You should use **Typespire.css**. So you have to put

```
<link href="Typespire.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

instead of

```
<link href="typespire.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```